# Getting Flask to accept chunked encoding

Tags: python, ffmpeg, flask

Is it possible to have Python Flask reading chunked encoding sent to it?

I have a very simple routine where I want to read the output from ffmpeg -progress  which sends progress updates via chunked encoding.

What happens though is Flask closes the connection after the first POST.

my routine is very simple

```
@app.route('/status', methods=['POST','GET'])
def get_status():
    logging.error(request.headers)
    logging.error(request.data)
    logging.error(request.args)
    return "OK"
```

What I see in the output is as follows and ffmpeg closes when the POST does

```
ERROR:root:Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Length:
User-Agent: Lavf/55.45.100
Connection: close
Host: localhost:50000
Accept: */*
Content-Type:


ERROR:root:
ERROR:root:ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

Excuse my lazy logging to error. Note in this case I am running Flask in debug mode but otherwise would like to run in Tornado or an equivalent simple container with permissions that make it easy to run command line programs like ffmpeg

Comment: Don't think that's possible, see: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/367

Comment: Providing that you want to keep connection open, shouldn't you consider Flask-SocketIO?

Comment: I will have a look at SocketIO and check back in here if I have luck. For now I am back to reading stdout